# Extract elements of list based on specific string and storing as a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list that has a few points of as shown below:

```
['Pros:', 'Pros 1', 'Pros 2','Cons:','Cons 1','Cons 2']
```

I am trying to have a Dataframe created with 2 columns, one called `Pros` and another called `Cons`

Expected output :

```
Pros, Cons
Pros 1; Pros 2,Cons 1; Cons 2
```

The problem I have is the `Pros` and `Cons` would differ in each list and hence I am trying to have all text before Cons categorized as one column and all items after Cons as the other column

Comment: @DeepSpace, I am trying to have the output stored as a Dataframe with 2 columns. One that has all `Pros` values and the other that has all `Cons` value. I used the semicolon to show multiple values that would be stored in the same row and comma to separate columns

Answer (score 0):

I'd take another approach. Use `zip_longest` to fill missing values with `None`. It's a better `pandas` practice and will make presenting/working with the data a bit easier.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import zip_longest

li = ['Pros:', 'Pros 1', 'Pros 2', 'Cons:', 'Cons 1', 'Cons 2', 'Cons 3']
cons_index = li.index('Cons:')
pros, cons = li[1:cons_index], li[cons_index + 1:]
df = pd.DataFrame(zip_longest(pros, cons), columns=['Pros', 'Cons'])
print(df)
```

Outputs

```
     Pros    Cons
0  Pros 1  Cons 1
1  Pros 2  Cons 2
2    None  Cons 3
```

If you insist on your approach, then

```
import pandas as pd

li = ['Pros:', 'Pros 1', 'Pros 2', 'Cons:', 'Cons 1', 'Cons 2', 'Cons 3']
cons_index = li.index('Cons:')
pros, cons = ';'.join(li[1:cons_index]), ';'.join(li[cons_index + 1:])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Pros': [pros], 'Cons': [cons]})
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am trying to get all the output of `Pros` and `Cons` in one row. Basically concat values of all `Pros` into one column and concat values of all `Cons` into one column

Comment: @KevinNash I understand that, that's why the answer starts with `I'd take another approach`, and it is explained why a bit after that

Comment: @KevinNash I updated the answer to include a way to get your output

Comment: thank you. I see what you meant but had to address this problem as such.